# Matlab Kalman /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: gcc, matlab-compiler

I'm following the `Matlab` coder `kalman` tutorial in `Matlab` help. When using `codegen`, there's an error as below:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

But there is `libstdc++.so.6` in `/lib/` and `/usr/lib`

Comment: What command did you use to compile you code? Also, is the source code C++ or C?

Comment: matlab code...codegen -report kalman02.m -args {z}

Comment: Might be a 32/64 bit issue. What kind of system do you have?

Comment: OK so that explains it. You need to either install 32-bit libraries, or use `-m64` compiler flag.

Answer (score 62):

For Fedora 16 use:

```
sudo yum install libstdc++-static
```

Comment: Fixed my problem on Fedora 21. Thanks!

Comment: The same, worked on Ubuntu but Fedora needed the above.

Comment: Wouldn't **build-essential** take care of all that?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `build-essential` is a Ubuntu package. OP uses Fedora.

Comment: I also needed this in Centos 7.5

Comment: Running `sudo dnf install libstdc++-static` saved my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can soft link the library to the name that is being sought

`ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so`

Comment: For Ubuntu 14 try: `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so`

Answer (score 6):

If you're compiling a **32-bit** application on a **64-bit CentOS 7**:

```
sudo yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Comment: Following this website (http://tech.yipp.ca/compile-error/install-libstdc-for-32-bit-on-64-bit-centos/), I found that the command: `sudo yum install libstdc++-static libstdc++-static.i686` is more appropriate. Tried in my machine and worked.

Answer (score 6):

i did **`sudo apt-get install g++-4.7`**  it work for me for matlab .

Answer (score 1):

For **CentOS**, be sure you have installed gcc-c++ package (it includes  libstdc++-devel dependency):

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```