# Migrating to CentOS7 from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libstdc++, centos7

I am trying to migrate my project from Ubuntu 12.04 to CentOS 7. The problem I am facing is upon linking, ld fails to find lstdc++, I have installed all possible versions of libstdc++ via `yum search <pattern>` but compiler still unable to find lstdc++. The same project when compiled on Ubuntu compiles fine without any issues. I was just wondering if it could be the location of the gcc libs that might be causing this problem? `ldconfig -v` does seem to list libsdtc++, so I was confident my compilation should go through fine. I was initially getting linking errors in -lm and -lc as well, but by installing certain packages `yum install glibc glibc-devel glibc-static`, I was able to move forward. lstdc++ is the one bugging me still. Any Ideas.

I also tried couple of links already posted which indicates how to install libstdc++, but none of them seem to fix my issue. Also, tried creating a soft link of libstdc++.so to libstdc++.s0.6.0.1 in /usr/lib but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a day of effort, i finally figured out the solution at [Matlab Kalman /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195110/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc) .

Never thought a solution for fedora would fix my problem for CentOS.