# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ for Ubuntu while trying to "swift build" Perfect2 project

Tags: swift, swift3, ubuntu-14.04, perfect

### Description:

I've followed the installation steps for [Swift3](https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads) and [Perfect2](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectDocs/blob/master/guide/gettingStarted.md)
and I've cloned the [PerfectTemplate](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate) test project proposed by Perfect and I've tried `swift build`

### Error Message:

> warning: minimum recommended clang is version 3.6, otherwise you may
>   encounter linker errors. Linking ./.build/debug/PerfectTemplate
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) :0: error: link
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   :0: error: build had 1 command failures error: exit(1):
>   /etc/swift301/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f
>   /home/XXXX/ClionProjects/PerfectTemplate/.build/debug.yaml

### What I've tried:

I've gone on different SO questions that seemed similar but all on different projects and attempted to try their solutions without luck:

For example:

[Matlab Kalman /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195110/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc)

I also noticed the warning coming from the clang version, I am aware that my current version is 3.4, but that is what was installed via `sudo apt-get install clang` as mentioned in the documentation.

I've also tried installing the 3.6 version of clang with: `sudo apt-get install clang-3.n`

However, after when I try `swift build` again I get the following error:

> error: invalid inferred toolchain: could not find `clang`

### Question:

How do I get rid of the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++` error, so I can build the PerfectTemplate project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this. It might not work, but it's worth a shot.

Update packages and dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install clang 3.6:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-3.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-3.6 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.6 100
```

I hope this helps, but apologies if it doesn't. Best of luck!

---

If this error appears:

> /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open
>   /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libstdc++.‌​so: No
>   such file or directory

It's most likely that the `libstdc++.so` symbolic link points to an inexisting file.

In my case it was pointing to:

> /usr/lib/libstdc++.so -> /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

Which was incorrect because `libstdc++.so.6` did not exist in that area. Simply find it's location via: `sudo find / -name libstdc++.so.6` which gave me:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Then recreate the link with:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
```

Comment: Hmm this is pretty good. Thanks. I'm getting a new error "/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libstdc++.so: No such file or directory" Any ideas?

Comment: Try to cd into the directory it's giving in the error, and then apt-get install the missing file. I'm not sure as to the specifics of the error, but it's obvious you're missing something. So try cd-ing down and apt-get install libstdc++.so ....based off what you put above that would be my first guess as to what you're missing.

Comment: it would appear so. I'm not getting any errors when I swift build. I'll test the run later on this week and I'll let you know if any more problems show up. Thank you for the help !

Comment: You're welcome! I'm so glad you got it working. Great job! Feel free to reach out if there is anything else and I'll be glad to help if I can.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same problem and update-alternatives didn't help me, but after

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

swift build ran successfully. Looks like some dependencies were deprecated.